# Faster and shorter way of finding views

Tags: android, android-view

Is there a quicker or shorter way to initialize all view in my layout than this:

```
    row2[0] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll22);
    row2A[0] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll22alt);
    row2B[0] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll22blank);
    mOffsiteDataBackup[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ll22_backup);
    mRam[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ll22_ram);
    mCpu[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ll22_cpu);
    mHdd[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ll22_hdd);
    mOs[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ll22_system);
    mStatusIcon[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ll22_image);
   .
   .
   .
```

It is really annoying to write lot of lines only to find views. Until I find all of them and initialize some listeners, my `onCreate` has more than 400 lines, which is something I certainly don't want.

Thanks for your tips !

Comment: You have > 400 UI elements in a single activity?

Comment: No I have more than 400 lines after writing listeners and so. I have around 70 elements.

Comment: 70 is still an extreme amount...

Comment: Yes, 70 is a lot, but they are never visible all at once, for example I have around 10 progress bars, which change their visibility to gone, after download has completed and some textViews are shown instead. That is one of the reasons I have so many XML elements.

Comment: See my answer, you should split the processes and ui up into fragments and reduce an excess of views in one view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any way you do it it's going to be around the same amount of typing, in some cases even more. 50> an extreme amount of views in an activity...

The only way I can think of making this smaller is splitting them up into Fragments and use the updated framework... 70 elements shouldn't be in one ui.. a ui is meant to be simple and easy to use. Not with lots of elements to it that distracts the user from the main task they want it for.

Comment: So I guess, I'll either split my activity into fragments or I just have to go with it as it is. Currently it is working fine, I just thought it would be nicer if my Activity didn't have so many lines. Thx for your time.

Comment: Pretty much, sorry I couldn't help more, I've often faced a similar problem, as soon as fragments came into play I adopted them because of this reason, it makes things more modular as well and easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

If few UI elements are  functional unity(like your progresBar and textView), you can create custom view with these elements. That makes code is much more clear, especially if you use more instances of this view in one activity.